# Upload file to Sharepoint from Data Factory

Tags: sharepoint, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

We are generating an extract file in Data Factory(blob) that we need to upload to a SharePoint location. Is there any service available in azure to do this activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to do this via Logic Apps.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

since your source is blob and destination s sharepoint , HTTP is not available as a sink in ADF . SO unfortunately you cannot use the REST API and also there is no direct connector to sharepoint.
So you can use Logic app or Azure function for the copy task from blob to sharepoint

Comment: Thank you Nandan. We are looking for vice versa. From Azure BLB to SharePoint.

Comment: Hey , sorry to have miss read.
Yes, there is no direct connector available for it. You would have to use either logic app, Azure function or Batch job with Logic app being the most easy one

Comment: Is it possible in Logic Apps? Let check that .